# Password 1 password 2 cannot override label in model form django

Tags: django, django-forms

So i was using crispy forms to display my register view as i wanted to override the defaults labels i ran into an issue when it comes to the password label and the confirmation password label, i simply cannot change then even when i override then as i did with the username one, would appreciate any help.

Here is the abstractuser model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
setor_escolhas = (
    ("R", "Revendedora"),
    ("C", "Concessionária"),
)
setor= models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=setor_escolhas, blank=False, null=False)
```

Here is mine register form:

```
class UserCadastroForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1','setor', 'password2' ]
    labels={'username':'Usuário','setor':'Setor da sua empresa','password1':'Senha'}
```

And here is mine template format

```
{% extends "APP_IVG/layout.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class= "content-section">
    <form method= "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class = 'form-group'>
            <legend class= "border-bottom mb-4"> Junte-se hoje</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <button class= "btn btn-outline-info" type= "submit"> Cadastre-se </button>
        </div>      
    </form>
    <div class= "border-top pt-3">
        <small class= "text-muted"> 
            Já tem uma conta? <a class= "ml-2" href = "{% url 'Login' %}"> Clique aqui </a>
        </small>
    </div>  
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it by two ways, override it in the `__init__` method

```
class UserCadastroForm(UserCreationForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.fields['password1'].label = 'password 1 label'
          self.fields['password2'].label = 'password 2 label'
```

Or you may just override form fields:

```
class UserCadastroForm(UserCreationForm):

   password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='password 1 label',
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
        help_text='HELP TEXT',
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='password 2 label',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
        strip=False,
        help_text='HELP TEXT',
    )
```